# The negation operator in Javascript ? how is it working?

Tags: javascript, variables, operators

I have code is below :

```
var x = 4 
var y = --x;
```

Why when I running the result is :

```
console.log("value of x: ",x); //outputs 3 
console.log("value of y: ",y); //outputs 3
```

Why not is :

```
console.log("value of x: ",x); //outputs 4 
console.log("value of y: ",y); //outputs 3
```

Comment: What is your current understanding of the prefix `--` operator? It is not equivalent to `x - 1`.

Comment: i'm not sure, I'm follow the tutorial

Comment: There's the problem. We expect our users to search other resources in these situations. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) have a look at Decrement.

Answer (score 1):

the [decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)) can be used both as a prefix, and as a suffix, and it has different behavior. In prefix position it means "decrement first, and then return the value" in postfix position it means "return the value first, and then decrement".

So `var y = --x` means "change x to equal itself -1, then assign the resulting value to y"

`var y = x--` means "assign the value of x to y, then change x to equal itself -1"

If you just want to do a calculation and not change what x equals, then do `var y = x - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here in `var y = --x;` `--x` will **set** `x` to `x-1` and returns the updated value.

> If `x` is 3, then `--x` sets `x` to 2 and returns 2, whereas `x--` returns 3 and, only then, sets `x` to 2.

Have a look at [Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators)

Comment: If you got your answer, you can select any of the answers as answered.